# How to remove symbolic links from mysql/PHP on Mac OS X?

Tags: php, mysql, macos, apache

I am getting the following error when I run PHP code via localhost on a Mac OS X 10.12 installation with apache2, mysql, and PHP.

```
Warning: mysqli_connect(): (HY000/2002): Too many levels of symbolic links in /Users/kevin/Sites/quest/includes/db_connection.php on line 7 Database connection failed: Too many levels of symbolic links (2002)
```

I have not found any recursive symbolic links in the usr/lib/php directory or the usr/local/mysql directories. How can I resolve this error?

```
    <?php
    define("DB_SERVER", "localhost");
    define("DB_USER", "<my usr>");
    define("DB_PASS", "<my pass>");
    define("DB_NAME", "<my db>");
        //creates a database connection
        $connection = mysqli_connect(DB_SERVER, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);
        // tests connection for errors
        if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die("Database connection failed: ".
                        mysqli_connect_error() .
                        " (" . mysqli_connect_errno() . ")"
            );
        }

    ?>
```

Comment: a loop in your links?

Comment: Sounds like a filesystem issue: [Too many levels of symbolic links osx Lion](//stackoverflow.com/q/9770658)